# Fetch Images from the page with XPATH on dynamically generated page (PHP)

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to fetch all the images from a certain page. This page has link like `www.website.com/#1234567`; however, when I load it with xpath or get_contents, this #1234567 part gets cut, and the portion of the page I'm looking for is not loaded.

There is a `<a href="#1234567">` button that triggers ajax and loads the rest of the page. Is there a way to 'click' it or somehow trigger this ajax within xpath?

Is there other solutions?

Thank you for your time.